# How to make a loading/intro animation popup while waiting for program to start up clutter/GTK+

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk, clutter

My program takes a few seconds to start up.  I am using clutter for the GUI, and I decided to try and make something pop up to indicate that the program is starting up.  I wanted to just have a logo pop up and rotate, then disappear when the program starts.

So in clutter, I figured I could just make a new stage (window) add an actor to it, make the and actor spin, in the first section of the main function.  The window will pop up right away, but with no content, but the content wont show until you launch the clutter main loop.

So I was just wondering how I might be able to achieve this using clutter or GTK+.

If you are familar with reaper 4, the audio recording program, this program does something similar to what I want to mine to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a splash screen. I'm unfamiliar with clutter, but I found this [GTK splash screen example](http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/splash-screen-with-gtk/).

However, I think you're taking the problem the wrong way. Splash screens are a bad idea because you just add overhead. What you need is improving your startup performance, by doing some CPU and/or IO profiling. Loading stuff on-demand, and not all at once will help.

Comment: Splash screens are not a bad idea. If you have a heavy application that needs to do a lot of loading and initializations before anything can be done, it is good to show that the computer is busy. The result can be that the user boots the aplication twice because loading takes to long which is mistaken then for not loading at all.

Comment: I disagree. You should strive instead to show your user interface as soon as possible, and load anything heavy either in the background, or on-demand.

Comment: You cannot disagree. Splash screens are a good idea on heavy applications. If you boot up windows, would you like to look at a blank screen for 20 seconds, or at a animation that shows you that it's loading and therefore takes 20.1 seconds? Adobe packages, same thing, they all have splash screens. Otherwise you wouldnt know that it was loading or working, and you will end up pressing it twice.

Comment: I can disagree, and that's what I do. And don't compare booting an OS with launching an application. BTW, a good Desktop Environment prevents you from running the same application twice by mistake, at least, that's one of the things I get by running GNOME 3. I'm not against having some visual feedback showing your application is loading (often, a busy mouse cursor is used), but this is not necessarily a splash screen.

Comment: Sometimes, yes, a splash scren may be needed, if your app takes a good amount of time. That may even be a good idea if the splash screen adds some info on what is being loaded, which help identifying the culprit on lengthy loadings, but most often, you should use your time to simplify the loading, not adding extra work to the CPU. On most applications, thinking on an on-demand loading will cut the extra seconds, and make the splash screen irrelevant. Splash screens only make slow things slower.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with Clutter. But I'm pretty sure it will be difficult to render an animation without a main loop running in any high level library.
I'd try to put the code that causes the delay into a separate thread and inform the main loop when the startup is done.

Comment: I'm trying a new approach just making a separate program to launch at start up.  But I cannot figure out the best way to close the intro program when the main program starts up.

Comment: Which platform are you developing for. Or is your program meant to be platform independent?

Comment: It is meant to be cross platform.  Right now I am developing it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what i use:

```
string splashfile = path_templ + "/splashimg.png";

GtkWidget *image=gtk_image_new_from_file(splashfile.c_str());
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(SplashWindow), image);


gtk_widget_show_all(SplashWindow);

//Cycle through all iterations (refresh everything in the GUI)
while (gtk_events_pending()){
    gtk_main_iteration();
}
sleep(1);

(... rest of code ...)

gtk_main ();
gdk_threads_leave ();
```

Especially that last part of while events pending is the key